# Follow my site`s link from first five google search results in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to make sure, that site is locating in first five google`s search results. After that i need to click on the site.

This code, is working not correctly for my issue.

```
cy.get('.rc > .a').should('have.length', 5);
```

In Python I implement it like this

```
first_five = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="r"]/a')[:5]

for link in first_five:
    if 'https://www.random.org/' in link.get_attribute('href'):
        link.click()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

`should('have.length', 5)` will expect that the previous command returned a subject with exactly 5 elements but you want to test that the URL you're looking for is within the first five links. I believe you can do it like this:

```
cy.visit('https://www.google.com/search?q=nasa');
cy.get('.rc:lt(5) > .r > a[href*="wiki/NASA"]').click({ force: true });
// `{ force: true }` because it's covered by another element or something.
```

This will test that there's an `<a>` within the first 5 results containing `wiki/NASA` in its `href` attribute.

Comment: I have an error 'CypressError: Cypress detected a cross origin error happened on page load:

This typically happens in one of three ways:

1. You clicked an <a> that routed you outside of your application
2. You submitted a form and your server redirected you outside of your application
3. You used a javascript redirect to a page outside of your application'

Comment: Yes, that’s correct because that’s what you’re doing.

Comment: Maybe you know, how is posible to fix it

Comment: Cypress allows you to visit a second domain in another test. Why do you want to do it from the click?

Comment: @AlexAnchi It's explained here https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages.html#Cypress-detected-a-cross-origin-error-happened-on-page-load

Answer (score 1):

By default Cypress [get()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get) uses jquery to process selectors,

> The querying behavior of this command matches exactly how [$(…)](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) works in jQuery().

but if you prefer xpath there is an optional package [cypress-xpath](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-xpath) which allows that syntax.

```js
cy.get('.rc > .r > a');

//OR

cy.xpath('//div[@class="r"]/a');
```

With a site like google search where results can vary from run to run, it might pay to use a more flexible combination of jquery/xpath and Cypress command composition.

For example, a related searches ***'People also ask'*** section pops up in different positions, but it also contains `.rc > .r > a` classes, and these searches likely have nothing to do with the ranking you want to test.

The following is one way you might handle it. If the test fails because of one of google's unexpected sections, you can easily add `console.log()` to review what is coming back.

```js
cy.visit('https://www.google.com/search?q=random');

cy.get('.rc > .r > a').as('searchResults');
// OR cy.xpath('//div[@class="r"]/a').as('searchResults');

cy.get('div.related-question-pair .rc > .r > a').as('relatedSearches');

cy.get('@searchResults').then($searchResults => {
  cy.get('@relatedSearches').then($relatedSearches => {

    // Results of cy.get() are jquery-wrapped, denote by '$' prefix
    // Unwrap with [...spread operator] or Array.from($searchResults)
    const links = [...$searchResults].filter(r => ![...$relatedSearches].includes(r));

    const refs = Cypress.$.map(links, link => link.href);
    //console.log(refs)

    const targetIndex = refs.findIndex(r => r.includes('calculator.net'));
    expect(targetIndex).to.be.lessThan(5);

    const targetLink = links[targetIndex];
    cy.wrap(targetLink).click();
  })
})
```